# How to get detailed stat by using instagram API

Tags: api, instagram

I really like instagram API because it's simple and intuitive.
So, I write analytics system where users will have an opportunity to sign in to my website via instagram and I need to obtain stat about the signed in users' pages, such as age, gender, country and city users who have visited  the signed in user's page ... But it seems to me, instagram does not give an opportunity to do it.
Is there a way of getting this info and what must I do for it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Instagram collects information such as age, gender, or even location. Looking through their [documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent) it seems like you can probably glean location information from their posts. This appears to be; however, unreliable since the location is tied with the content they post.